# Help solve an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I'm preparing for the SAT and tripped over the following problem:

$(x-8)(x-k) = x^2 - 5kx + m$

"In the equation above, k and m are constants. If the equation is true for all values of x, what is the value of m?
A) 8
B) 16
C) 24
D) 32
E) 40
"
Can someone please explain how to solve it?

Comment: Open $(x-8)(x-k) and compare its values with RHS

Comment: Expand the L.H.S., compare co-efficients of like powers of $x$ on both sides and then solve for $k$ and $m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(x-8)(x-k) = x^2 - (k+8)x + 8k = x^2 - 5kx + m$. Thus:

$k + 8 = 5k$, and $m = 8k$.

So: $k = 2$, and $m = 16$

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I wonder is why I cannot get to something meaningful when I reach x = (m-8k) / (4k - 8)